# With Node SEA, how to pack node_modules into executable?

Tags: node.js, executable

This new [«Single Executable Applications»](https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html) feature sounds cool but it's not clear how to use node module packages from SEA application.

I know it mentions assets:

```json
  "assets": {
    "a.jpg": "/path/to/a.jpg",
    "b.txt": "/path/to/b.txt"
  }
```

But by pointing to entire folder, this doesn't seem to work:

```json
{
  "main": "hello.js",
  "output": "sea-prep.blob",
  "assets": {
    "node_modules": "./node_modules"
  }
}
```

How to pack node_modules?

Comment: Why not create a bundle with a tool like webpack or esbuild?

Comment: @DanielA.White but do they support SEA?

Comment: Why wouldn’t it? It makes a single script file